# add files to a bootable dvd

Tags: backup, boot, restore, iso-image

I have a restore cd image that is roughly 200mb. The restore cd takes a disc image and copies it back unto a hd. I would like to put my 3gb image with it and hope it is found.

How do i modify an iso to take in my disc image without breaking bootability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try magiciso(http://www.magiciso.com/)  it will allow you to mount the cd image and modify it. The only issue is that the trial limits you to a 300mb disc image I believe.  I believe poweriso also provides this functionality; they do provide a fully functional shareware copy.

Answer (score 0):

You want to retain bootability with the 200MB image and still use the remaining space on the DVD.

If your DVD Writing software lets you create multiple sessions with the first one carrying the bootable 200mb image and the later session carrying data, this could possibly work.
It would also require the ability of letting the first session remain bootable.
Have never actually tried it.

Why not use a CD instead of a DVD and forget the lesser wasted space?
Or, even the 3+ GB on a DVD -- these media are quite cheap.
You might end up wasting more media in these attempts.

Maybe, you have a mass production interest in which case getting this working (if feasible) might be worth a few attempts.

Comment: "Why not use a CD instead of a DVD and forget the lesser wasted space?" <-- dvds are actually cheaper then CDs (i think this has something to do with a RIAA tax since stereos can play cds and not dvds). Also it would be nice if i can launch recovery and have the image on the same disc instead of dvd + usb or alternative HD (or network support but the recovery app doesnt have drivers for my PC to enable boot network support)